# How To Use rows.NextResultSet() with database/sql

Tags: sql, go

`rows.NextRestultSet()` is returning false after the first set for rows... The documentation makes this sound straight forward, but it's not working for me. I'm using [github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb](https://github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb).

Here is an example of my code:

```
rows, err := db.Query(`
   Query1;
   Query2;
   Query3;
`)

for rows.Next() {
// scan
// check error
}

if !rows.NextResultSet() {
   log.Println("Expected another result set.")
// return some error
}

for rows.Next() ...
// continue process with 2nd result set, but code will not run up until this point
```

Answer (score 2):

`rows.NextResultSet()` would return false suggests that there is no next set of rows. You should use it in a ***do-while*** structured loop!

```
for cont := true; cont; cont = rows.NextResultSet() {
  for rows.Next() {
    // scan
    // check error
  }
}
```

Comment: You are right in that it is working correctly. My issue was different but I appreciate the help!